# 400 vs 401 http responses : which one is evaluated/returned first?

Tags: c#, http, http-post, webclient

I have been trying to make a post request with C# using Webclient. I was getting 400 bad request.When I adjusted the headers, and added authorization to it,I started getting 401 authorization error.Now i commented out the authorization, 400 bad request is back. So my question is: when it was returning 400, does it mean the server authenticated me and that something might be wrong with my json or can 400 be returned even before authentication is done? Below is my code.

```
    public static string Post(string json, string encoded){
     try{
          string url = "https://blah/rest/api/blah";
          ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
          var client = new WebClient();
          client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
          IWebProxy wp = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
          wp.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
          client.Proxy = wp;
          //client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + encoded;
          client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
          client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
          var response = client.UploadString(url, "POST",json);
          return response
        }
         catch(Exception e){
            return e
        }

     
}
```

Comment: Best way of debugging is use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Test with a working application like postman or a webbrowser.  Then compare the headers in the working with the c# code.  Usually you need to add a missing header like a particular browser type.  The sniffer will show the SSL/TTL and if you get past the SSL/TLS then you know the issue is with the headers or syntax of the request.

Comment: It depends upon your requirements and the way its implemented. its not a standard which error should be handled first or programmed first. But Generally 401 and 403 errors are checked first as Auth Headers are read and validated before reading the content of the request.

Comment: I used fiddler to debug. I see result is 200. Under inspectors -> auth, it says "no authorization header is present" even though i sent the request with encoded base64 authorization. Also under json it says invalid text at position, but the json is not displayed. I have sent this same json with Postman and it worked. The json i'm sending in code is serialized with json.net and JsonLint validated the string as valid json. So i really do not know what i'm doing wrong. So frustrating.

Comment: Finally resolved it. DisplayNameAttribute marked on a property in my serialization model had a white space character before the closing quotation mark. Using Fiddler helped me discovered this. Thanks @jdweng

Comment: It was the json string that you were posting that had the error.